# Загрузка фотографий в несуществующую запись

Tags: php, yii

Кто-нибудь реализовывал агрузку фотографий к еще несуществующей записи?

Ну например, я создаю новый товар или альбом, но его в базе фактически еще нет, он еще не создан, а фотографии хочется заливать.

Как кто решает этот вопрос? У меня есть идея только с временной папкой, после создания записи, переносить там фотографии, а временную папку очищать.

Comment: В чем проблема создать альбом в момент прихода первой фотографии?

Answer (score 1):

Делал через папку для временных файлов. В случае реального создания записи - перемещается в соответствующий каталог. Если создание прервано (а картинка загружена), при следующей загрузке идет сканирование файлов в папке функцией [filectime()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filectime.php), если оно отличается больше чем на N (например 3600) от текущего времени - удаляем файл. Проверка на время создания нужна, чтобы не удалить файлы параллельно работающего юзера.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы товар или альбом которого фактически еще нет просто помечать как еще не активный?

в таком случае, от него всегда можно будет избавиться если он вдруг никогда не станет нужным.